# Issue with method onPause() if i Change orientation of device

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle

I inserted into onPause() a call to logout the user; but when i change the orientation of android device the method onPause is invoked same.

WHY? I don't need to invoke the method logoutUser if i turn the device to horizontal/portrait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `Activity` is recreated whenever we change the orientation of the phone. Check [Handling Runtime Changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html).

> Some device configurations can change during runtime (such as screen orientation, keyboard availability, and language). When such a change occurs, Android restarts the running Activity (onDestroy() is called, followed by onCreate())

The reason behind recreation is that the app may want to change the layout based on the new orientation.

But in most cases you don't need to recreate your `Activity` each time the user changes phone orientation since you can get callback on your `Activity`'s `onConfigurationChanged()` and make the required layout changes. You can disable them by adding following line in your `Activity` tag within your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".activity.ScrollableTabsActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_scrollable_tabs"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.ScrollableTabsActivity"></activity>

Answer (score 1):

When we change the orientation of activity for example horizontal to portrait that time activity is recreated so according to android activity life cycle OnPause() method will get called.

To avoid invoke of method logoutUser you have to save current status of user using  onSavedInstanceState() method.

Refer this link for more understanding 
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Comment: mmm and what i must insert into onSavedInstanceState method to avoid invoke logoutUser?